# Adding reactions by a bot in VB

Tags: vb.net

My bot sends an embed message to a specific channel, after that it automatically ads a reaction to the message.

Examples: "" and ""

Button to send the embed: (works fine)

```
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Dim embed As New EmbedBuilder With {
                   .ThumbnailUrl = discord.CurrentUser.GetAvatarUrl,
                   .Title = "Just title.",
                   .Description = "Enjoy",
                   .Color = New Discord.Color(255, 0, 0)
                                        }
    
discord.GetGuild("12345..").GetTextChannel("54321..").SendMessageAsync("", False, embed)
End Sub
```

---

Now how to make it add the two reactions after the message is sent? ("" and "")

> I figured out that it could work with the message received handler, here's what I tried. (I'm not sure if it works)

```
 Private Async Function onMsg(message As SocketMessage) As Task

 If message.Source = MessageSource.Bot Then
 Dim reaction As SocketReaction
 Dim rMessage = CType(Await message.Channel.GetMessageAsync(message.Id), RestUserMessage)

 If reaction.Emote.Name.Equals("") AndAlso
    reaction.Emote.Name.Equals("")
    Else
    Dim my_emo1 As Emoji = ("")
    Dim my_emo2 As Emoji = ("")
    rMessage.AddReactionAsync(my_emo1)
    rMessage.AddReactionAsync(my_emo2)
 End If
 End Function
```

---

Comment: 1. You should `await` your `async` calls.  
2. You can simply store the message and add a reaction to it. No need to go through the MessageReceived event   
3. You declare `reaction as SocketReaction`, which is not set to anything and yet you try to get `reaction.Emote.Name`....that line will always fail. 4. You need to build your embed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your current code:

```vb
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Dim embed As New EmbedBuilder With {
                   .ThumbnailUrl = discord.CurrentUser.GetAvatarUrl,
                   .Title = "Just title.",
                   .Description = "Enjoy",
                   .Color = New Discord.Color(255, 0, 0)
                 }

Dim msg = Await discord.GetGuild("12345..").GetTextChannel("54321..").SendMessageAsync(embed:=embed.Build)

Dim my_emo1 As New Emoji("")
Dim my_emo2 As New Emoji("")

Await msg.AddReactionAsync(my_emo1)
Await msg.AddReactionAsync(my_emo2)
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked, but just change "(embed:=embed.Build)" To be "("", False, embed)", You are awsome.!